# How to change color of shape particles on hover? Particle JS?

Tags: javascript, particles.js

I want to change the dots and lines colours of particles on the hover?
Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you show what you currently have?

Comment: Welcome to SO! I recommend new or returning users review [ask] for tips on how to form their posts in a way that best enables the community to provide assistance.  Generally, if you can include a [mcve] in your question it will make it easier for others to provide you feedback specific to your code.

Comment: I do not think it is possible, see: [issue #466](https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js/issues/466#issuecomment-784307828)